# PHP way to execute SQL LIKE matching without a database query?

Tags: php, sql, pattern-matching, full-text-search, sql-like

I want to match an input string to my PHP page the same way a match done by the LIKE command in SQL (MySQL) for consistency of other searches.  Since (I have seen but don't comprehend) some of the PHP syntax includes SQL commands I am wondering if this is possible?

The reason for this is I am now implementing a search of a keyword versus fields in the DB that are stored in a serialized array, which I have to unserialize in PHP and search depending on the structure of the array.  I can't query against the table, just need the matching ability of the query.  Otherwise I need to find an alternate matching routine, which won't be consistent.  I can't go back and re-structure the DB since this wasn't anticipated wayyy back in the spec.  Yes, I need an ugly hack, but am looking for the most elegant.

If it's not possible I could use any recommendation of matching user typed text as a keyword against stored text.

EDIT (for clarification): my main problem is I don't have a thorough grasp on how the LIKE command works (just copying the code) and as the keyword implies some degree of vagueness, I would like that  vagueness preserved if I switch to a regular expression.  I am better with regex's just not so good with like.  My query is "LIKE 'matchme%'"

Comment: How does the query look from the user's perspective? Are they allowed to type wildcards like "%" or do they only enter straight text?

Comment: the user supplies the text, I add the wildcards behind the scenes.  I do use one %.  LIKE 'text%'

Comment: Dude - LIKE is deterministic. It is string search. Do it in the DB.

Comment: Matt, its stored as a serialized array in the db. I dont know why, but its right there in his text.

Comment: OIS: Yeah I see that now. My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update

Based on tomalak's comment and OIS's brilliant idea to use preg_grep, this might be something more along the lines of a final solution for you.

```
<?php

function convertLikeToRegex( $command )
{
    return "/^" . str_replace( '%', '(.*?)', preg_quote( $command ) ) .  "$/s";
}

function selectLikeMatches( $haystack, $needle )
{
    return preg_grep( convertLikeToRegex( $needle ), $haystack );
}

$likeClauses = array(
    '%foo'
    ,'foo%'
    ,'%foo%'
);

$testInput = array(
    'foobar'
    ,'barfoo'
    ,'barfoobaz'
);

foreach ( $likeClauses as $clause )
{
    echo "Testing $clause:";
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( selectLikeMatches( $testInput, $clause ) );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

### Original Post Below

Is this along the lines of what you're after?

```
<?php

function convertLikeToRegex( $command )
{
    return "/^" . str_replace( '%', '(.*?)', $command ) .  "$/s";
}

$likeClauses = array(
    '%foo'
    ,'foo%'
    ,'%foo%'
);

$testInput = array(
    'foobar'
    ,'barfoo'
    ,'barfoobaz'
);

foreach ( $testInput as $test )
{
    foreach ( $likeClauses as $clause )
    {
        echo "Testing '$test' against like('$clause'): ";
        if ( preg_match( convertLikeToRegex( $clause ), $test ) )
        {
            echo 'Matched!';
        } else {
            echo 'Not Matched!';
        }
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

Comment: Why not encapsulate all the regex stuff in a function: "Like(haystack, needle)"? This way you the function call was more more readable and no one could mess with the way the function works from outside. Also, $command needs to be escaped with "\Q" and "\E" or it will fail at some point.

Comment: Also, the replacement does not need to use the lazy dot nor a capturing group.

Comment: @BaileyP: I think convertLikeToRegex() does not need to be a separate function. I can see no real use for the result, outside of selectLikeMatches(). I gave my +1 earlier already.

Comment: The Q poster has an array with text, and gets a search string. He adds % for sql search or ^/$ for regex search. Converting from sql like search string to regex search string is going around the core problem, which is searching an array for a text.

Comment: @BailyP: 1) how does this solve the original question again? 2) this is elegant to you?

Comment: @crescentfresh 1) Kind of impossible to tell since I don't know exactly what tkotitan's data looks like. But it does give valid results per my test input.  2) I deliberately wrote it so he could uses the LIKE syntax to search PHP strings. By that very nature it's going to be a tad clunky.

Comment: @BaileyP: which is the data that comes from the user? $likeClauses or $testInput? It's not clear at all what your testing exactly.

Comment: It would be the $likeClauses - they exists in this post only as an example.  I would leave it up to tkotitan to generate the search atoms in his final implementation - which I think he understands.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is [preg_grep](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) actually.

```
$arr = array("tstet", "duh", "str");
$res = preg_grep("#st#i", $arr); //i for case insensitive
var_dump($res);
```

results in

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "tstet"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "str"
}
```

edit:

> the user supplies the text, I add the
>   wildcards behind the scenes. I do use
>   one %. LIKE 'text%'

here is how you specify it in regex

```
"#st#i"  regex is the same as in sql "%st%"
"#^st#i" regex is the same as in sql "st%"
"#st$#i" regex is the same as in sql "%st"
```

Also, remember to use [preg_quote](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on any text you get from a third party.
$regex = "#" . preg_quote($text) . "#i";
$res = preg_grep($regex, $arr);

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you'd need [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) but that's not exactly the same behavior as a LIKE.

```
<?php // The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search 
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found."; 
} else {
    echo "A match was not found."; } 
?>
```

Comment: There is no need to use regular expressions, I would use faster strpos().

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to be able to check if the input string is LIKE var% ?

You could use strpos(haystack, needle) to match %var%.

```
if( strpos($source, "var") == 0 ) echo "matches var%";
if( strlen($source) - (strpos($source, "var")) == strlen("var") ) echo "matches %var";
```

That is pretty ugly. And actually probably not the most elegant.

Comment: First test should be === 0 since if var is not in $source strpos returns false which is == 0 but not === 0.

Comment: %var is substr($source,-strlen("var")) == "var"