# PHP - searching string with database LIKE syntax/wildcards (%, _)

Tags: php, regex, string, sql-like

I have an application receiving search requests using the syntax of a database `LIKE` notation (ex: `%someth_ng%`), but I must be able to apply this search not only to a database (which is straightforward), but to strings in my application, which is in PHP.

I'm thinking that using a regex is probably the best way to do this, but I'd like to see what solutions other people can/have come up with.

Comment: maybe useful: [PHP way to execute SQL LIKE matching without a database query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562823/php-way-to-execute-sql-like-matching-without-a-database-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of work, this is the best I could come up with:

```
public function like($needle, $haystack)
{
    // Escape meta-characters from the string so that they don't gain special significance in the regex
    $needle = preg_quote($needle, '~');

    // Replace SQL wildcards with regex wildcards
    $needle = str_replace('%', '.*', $needle);
    $needle = str_replace('_', '.', $needle);

    // Add delimiters, modifiers and beginning + end of line
    $needle = '~^' . $needle . '$~isu';

    return (bool) preg_match($needle, $haystack);
}
```

I'm curious to see if there are any better solutions, or improvements to this one.

Comment: Please edit your original post to place additional information there.

Comment: Is this a self answering question or an addition to your original question? If this is additional you should edit the question to include this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Comment: It's a self answering question, but I was curious to see if anyone else had a better solution. I'll edit this answer to make that a bit more clear.